# While statements - Cant understand a concept

Tags: c++, loops, variables, while-loop, statements

I am currently learning C++ and right now I am stuck on while statements.
The thing is I cant understand properly what is the difference between initializing a variable just before start of the while statement or if the variable is initialized globally in the main.

The piece of code below will probably explain my question better:

```
int main()
{
using namespace std;
int x = 1;
while (x <= 5)
{
    int y = 1;
    while (y <= x)
    {
        cout << y++ << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    ++x;
}

return 0;

}
```

This code outputs as:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

but the following

```
int main()
{
using namespace std;
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
while (x <= 5)
{
    //int y = 1;
    while (y <= x)
    {
        cout << y++ << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
    ++x;
}

return 0;
}
```

produces :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Well it probably sounds stupid but I really need to understand it. I have gone through a couple of topics but the place of initialization of variable just doesn't get to me in this. If someone can point me out in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In the first version, `y` has a value of `1`  at the start of the `while (x <= 5)` loop,   In the second, in the second iteration, the value is whatever resulted at the end of the first iteration, and so on.

Comment: In the second program `y` keeps its value from the first outer loop iteration, to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y = 1` is initialized again and again when the first while loop starts in the first case.

In the second case it is not initialized again i.e it reaches the value of x and does not enter the second while loop.

Comment: oh I get it. I think that's why it changes its output because if initialized globally it starts with 1 just first time and then increments every time. But in the first every time it starts with 1 and has to increment to a certain level before the while statement evaluates. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right, but the initialization you do is not `global` it is still called `local` initialization, a `global initialization` would be to declare the variables outside the main function.

Comment: oh right, yeah I still need to get a hang on this stuff. Thanks though. Your answer cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

In second code it's all because value of `y` has never been reset to `y=1`.

Whereas in first case you are always assigning `int y=1` whenever `while()` loop check condition and enter into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop in your example shows that for every value of x, the y variable will be initialized again to 1 and values of y will go up to x(meaning you are initializing y to 1 every time x increases).

Bur for second example, y is initialized only once and it's last value will be used every time x values increases(changes).

Answer (score 0):

`while` is used for looping, in the first program you are initialising `y=1` each time when your while loops. In the second program all the times it gets `y=1` as it is not being looped. Hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its not so much about initialisation, but rather about assignment. Here is how your codes get executed, roughly:

#### First case

1. Allocate memory for x and y
2. Set x to 1
3. Check if x is less than 5, otherwise go to 9
4. Set y to 1
5. Check if y is less than x, otherwise go to 8
6. Print y
7. Increment y, go to 5
8. Increment x, go to 3
9. End

#### Second case

1. Allocate memory for x and y
2. Set x to 1
3. Set y to 1
4. Check if x is less than 5, otherwise go to 9
5. Check if y is less than x, otherwise go to 8
6. Print y
7. Increment y, go to 5
8. Increment x, go to 4
9. End

Notice how points 3 and 4 have swapped between the two cases.